# group json data using date time

Tags: javascript, json

I need to gruop my json data by date , month ,week and day.
I use REST API and there is no way to get grouped json data.
I need to group data by month, weeks and days :
so it's a cascading json object

> year:{ month:{day1:{data1, data2...}, 
>                 day2:{..}},
>          month2:{..}} ,

any other ideas.

this my first function to get data :

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, "Activites", "", FillFormat_JSONDate, "");


function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {

    // Executing our items via an ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results

        },
        error: function (data) {
            //failure(data);
            alert("failure");
        }
    });

}


function FillFormat_JSONDate(dataitems) {

    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(dataitems.d.results);
    var jsonPars = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    //map data from SPList to Array
    var jsonYearformat = {};
    var SPListItemP = $.map(jsonPars, function (item) {

        var date = new Date(item.Created);
      //  push data into jsonYearformat

        return false;
    });

}
```

Comment: What do the first two lines of this function accomplish? It looks like you encode it into a JSON string, then immediately decode it again... why?

Comment: What is the format of dataitems? is it a table format?

Comment: dataitems it's a json object : dataitems.d.results and yes its a table format

Answer (score 0):

i use this code to get the grouping :

```
 i = 0,
    groups = {};
    var year;
    var day;
    var month;
    var SPListItemP = $.map(jsonPars, function (item) {

        elt = new Date(item.IPS_START);
            year = elt.getFullYear();
            month = elt.getMonth() + 1;
            day = elt.getDate();

            groups[year] || (groups[year] = {}); // exists OR create {}
            groups[year][month] || (groups[year][month] = []);
            groups[year][month][day] || (groups[year][month][day] = []);  // exists OR create []
            groups[year][month][day].push(item);

        return false;
    });
```